# Cleaner and Efficient way of providing a responsive layout in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

At the moment this is my attempt a responsive layout, so I have some images. When the screen is really small I change it from this:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <ul class="ul-class-name">
        <li><img src="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="visible-xs">
    <ul class="imageslider">
        <li><img src="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So what I've done is make it into an image slider when the screen is really small which is pretty effective

The code ends up being very long with multiple `li` tags and is just duplicate code with the exception of the name of the `ul` class. This meansI end up with a some big code for the normal div, and some more very very similar big code with the only difference being the `ul class="imageslider"`

What is a more efficient or cleaner way of putting this responsive idea into the code?

UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.imageslider').bxSlider({

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing what you're proposing. The cleanest way is to try and keep the same class names, and just giving them a different behavior depending on the screen size.

You'll notice bootstrap uses "special" sizes, such as **xs** **sm** or **md**.

> md > 991px
>
> 991px >= sm > 767px
>
> 767px >= xs

Now nowing this you can create your website around these predefined sizes. All you need to do is have a default behavior and then when a specific size is detected well then you change it's behavior. For example:

**default:**

```
.imageslider {
   max-width: 700px;
}
```

**mobile device size**

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
 .imageslider {
   max-width: 300px;
   background-color: blue;
 }
}
```

Or you could actually use both class names like so:

```
<ul class="ul-class-name imageslider">
```

and you could specifically say well, I want imageslider to activate for mobile devices only: thus you give your default behavior to *ul-class-name* and your responsive "behavior" to *imageslider*.

( just replace the default imageslider to default ul-class-name in the example above, but I do not find this very clean. )

Comment: hey, I realised I am using a jQuery based image slider, does this change how you would approach it? I could include `imageslider` into the `ul` class then as you said, and calculate the width using JS instead, not sure how though but it seems more logical given that the slider initiates using JS

Comment: To answer your question, no playing around with the imageslider will not effect the jQuery events placed on it. However, if you are using an imageslider - I recommend you use the carousel that comes with bootstrap. For me it was relatively easy to use. You just have to know how to play around with position: absolute; / relative for certain aspects. Here is an example of a carousel http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ ( a carousel can be used as an imageslider. For example, wwwl.almedia.fr )

Comment: thanks I will try this instead then and try your method above. Will post back to update on my progress

Comment: I've tried implementing your code with no luck. How would you make the imageslider only activate for mobile devices?

Comment: Set the default image slider to hidden, then if you detect mobile device you "unhide" it. Check this website out http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/